# trigger auto_increment oracle without sequence

Tags: oracle, triggers

I created a trigger to manage the auto_increment but for the reason that I do not know it always shows me this error: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER auto_increment BEFORE INSERT ON people FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
    mat number;            
    namm varchar(40);            
    coun number;

BEGIN          
  namm:=:new.name;      

  IF inserting() THEN    T
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO coun FROM people;  

        IF coun = 0 THEN                                
            INSERT INTO people VALUES(100,namm);
        ELSE
            SELECT MAX(:old.matricule+1) INTO mat FROM people;
            INSERT INTO people (matricule,name) VALUES(mat,namm);
        END IF;                      
  END IF;
```

END;

Answer (score 2):

It is recursive because every time a record is inserted into PEOPLE your trigger inserts another record into PEOPLE, which causes the trigger to fire and insert yet another record into PEOPLE, which... well you get the idea.

In an Oracle trigger you just set the :NEW values to change what is being inserted e.g.:

```
:NEW.matricule := 100;
```

However, your trigger still would not work because it selects from the same table, which will cause the "table is mutating" exception.

Really the best answer here is to use a sequence - they are designed to avoid these issues as well as giving the best performance.  But if you **really** need this increment functionality, do it before inserting not in a trigger.